# Interpretation of $\text{Hom}_{k}(k^n,W) \rightarrow W^{\bigoplus n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I understand the map between $k^n$ and $W$ can be constructed by first mapping the basis vectors in $k^n$ with $n$ vectors in $W$ and then extrapolating the map from there. But I am unsure about how to think of the map between the homomorphism and $W^{\bigoplus n}$.

Comment: The homomorphism is the one which sends $T\in \text{Hom}(k^n,W)$ to the tuple of vectors $(T(e_1),\dots, T(e_n))\in W^{\oplus n}$. The inverse takes a tuple of vectors and constructs the unique linear transformation which maps the standard basis to those vectors.

Comment: Map the canonical basis vectors to coordinates. Basically you're making an $n \times n$ matrix out of them with respect to the basis.

Comment: Are you happy interpreting the canonical isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}_k(k, W) \cong W$, via $f \mapsto f(1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence "a map between $k^n$ and $W$ can be constructed by first mapping the basis vectors of $k^n$ in $W$ and then extrapolating from there" means the following:

> For any $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n \in W$ there exists a unique linear map $f \colon k^n \to W$ such that
> $$
> f(e_1)=w_1, f(e_2)=w_2, \dots, f(e_n)=w_n.
> $$

Obviously, $e_1,\dots,e_n$ are the standard basis vectors of $k^n$.

In other words:

> For any $(w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n) \in W^n$ there exists a unique $f \in \text{Hom}_k(k^n,W)$ such that
> $$
> (f(e_1),f(e_2),\dots,f(e_n)) = (w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n).
> $$

In other words:

> The map
> \begin{align}
> \text{Hom}_k(k^n,W) & \stackrel \phi \longrightarrow W^n \\
> f & \longmapsto (f(e_1),f(e_2),\dots,f(e_n))
> \end{align}
> is bijective.

Moreover, you can prove that $\phi$ is linear, so $\phi$ is an isomorphism.